# Within parsing html to dom tree, how to split string by tag in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

Here is the string:

```
<div>This is a test.</div>
<div>This <b>another</b> a test.</div>
<div/>
<div>This is last a test.</div>
```

I wanna to separate the following string to array like this:

```
{"This is a test.", "This <b>another</b> a test.", "", "This is last a test."}
```

Any idea to do so in php? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you want a piece of code to do this / method to write this yourself (probably using a regexp?), but If you just want to get the job done, you might want to take a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ . Maybe overkill to use a big library for one string, otoh, you might need to parse more later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your HTML is malformed on purpose

There are many options, includin xpath and numerous libraries. [Regex is not a good idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). I find [**DOMDocument**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) fast and relatively simple.

getElementsByTagName then iterate over them getting the innerHTML.

**Example:**

```
<?php
function get_inner_html( $node ) { 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 

    return $innerHTML; 
}
$str = <<<'EOD'
<div>This is a test.</div>
<div>This <b>another</b> a test.</div>
<div/>
<div>This is last a test.</div>
EOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$ellies = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($ellies as $one_el) {
    if ($ih = get_inner_html($one_el))
        $array[] = $ih;
}
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($array); ?>
</pre>

// Output
// Note that there would be
// a 4th array elemnt w/o the `if ($ih = get_inner_html($one_el))` check:
Array
(
    [0] => This is a test.
    [1] => This <b>another</b> a test.
    [2] => This is last a test.
)
```

[**Try it out here**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rof3rj)

---

**Note:**

The above will work fine as long as you don't have nested DIVS. If you do have nesting, you have to exclude the nested children as you loop through innerHTML.

For example let's say you have this HTML:

```
<div>One
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
<div/>
<div>Four
    <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

Here's how to deal with the above and get an array that has the number in order:

**Dealing with nesting**

```
<?php
function get_inner_html_unnested( $node, $exclude ) { 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) {     
        if (!property_exists($child, 'tagName') || ($child->tagName != $exclude)) 
            $innerHTML .= trim($child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ));
    } 

    return $innerHTML; 
}
$str = <<<'EOD'
<div>One
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
<div/>
<div>Four
    <div>Five</div>
</div>
EOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$ellies = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($ellies as $one_el) {
    if ($ih = get_inner_html_unnested($one_el, 'div'))
        $array[] = $ih;
}
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($array); ?>
</pre>
```

[**Try it out here**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Dmf8V)

Answer (score 0):

This `make_array` function should do the trick for you:

```
function make_array($string)
{
    $regexp = "(\s*</?div/?>\s*)+";
    $string = preg_replace("@^$regexp@is", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("@$regexp$@is", "", $string);
    return preg_split("@$regexp@is", $string);
}
```

When passed the string you gave as an example, it outputs the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "This is a test."
    [1] => "This <b>another</b> a test."
    [2] => "This is last a test."
)
```

Comment: What about `<div>yes 1</div>no<div>yes 2</div>`? ==> http://codepad.viper-7.com/wZycaN

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer: [Regex is not a good idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)